# Why doesn't Supergirl enlist Superman's help when all humanity is threatened in the season 1 finale?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, supergirl

In Supergirl Season 1 finale, Non and Indigo have triggered a device that is going to kill all of humanity in the next 4 hours. Martian, the only other superhero around, is hurt. No normal human is able to get close to the device to assist Supergirl and Supergirl has to go on a suicide mission to try to fight Kryptonians. If she loses or if they just stall her long enough, all humans of earth die.

What is the compelling reason for her to not call Superman? The situation is dire enough.

Comment: obviously, they hadn't cast him yet

Comment: Did you miss [this scene](http://utbgeek.com/home/bradu25/public_html/utbgeek/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/SG3-1.jpg)? Superman was out for the count.

Comment: @KutuluMike That's ok, they have shown him before as a blurred figure etc. They didn't have to show his face, they could've just shown him to be away or wounded by Kryptonite or whatever to explain his absence. My point is that the narrative becomes completely senseless without some sort of explanation for the absence of one person who's seemingly readily available and willing and able to help, specially when the cost can be death of all humanity. It distracts from the story.

Comment: @Oliver_C Oh I see, I didn't see this. Did they explain what had happened to Superman?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When Non first set off his Myriad device, Superman did fly in to help. He was caught in the device's grip and turned into a slave like everyone else. It was hypothesized that being raised by humans from the time he was very young had affected his brain enough to make him susceptible to Myriad; Kara, being raised by Krpytonians until she was a bit older, was immune.

After they freed everyone from Myriad's control the first time, for some reason, Superman does not wake up. You can see him being tended to by the doctors at the DEO (well, his boots at least) in the middle of the episode:

[image: Superman's Boots]

> GENERAL LANE: So, how is it that Superman is still down for the count?
>
> LUCY LANE: We don't know; we're hoping he regains consciousness soon.